# What is the difference between Big Data and Data Mining?

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, bigdata, data-mining, data-science

As Wikpedia states

> The overall goal of the data mining process is to extract information
>   from a data set and transform it into an understandable structure for
>   further use

How is this related with Big Data? Is it correct if I say that Hadoop is doing data mining in a parallel manner?

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow, because it is too opinion-based.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### Big data is everything

Big data is a *marketing* term, not a technical term. Everything is big data these days. My USB stick is a "personal cloud" now, and my harddrive is big data. Seriously. This is a totally unspecific term that is largely defined by what the marketing departments of various very optimistic companies can sell - and the C*Os of major companies buy, in order to make magic happen. Update: and by now, the same applies to **data science**. It's just marketing.

### Data mining is the old big data

Actually, data mining was just as overused... it could mean anything such as

- collecting data (think NSA)
- storing data
- machine learning / AI (which predates the term data mining)
- **non-ML data mining** (as in "knowledge discovery", where the term data mining was actually coined; but where the focus is on new knowledge, not on learning of existing knowledge)
- business rules and analytics
- visualization
- anything involving data you want to sell for truckloads of money

It's just that marketing needed a new term. "Business intelligence", "business analytics", ... they **still keep on selling the same stuff**, it's just rebranded as "big data" now.

### Most "big" data mining isn't big

Since most methods - at least those that give interesting results - just don't scale, most data "mined" isn't actually big. It's clearly much bigger than 10 years ago, but not big as in Exabytes. A survey by KDnuggets had something like 1-10 GB being the average "largest data set analyzed". That is not big data by any data management means; it's only large by what can be analyzed using *complex* methods. (I'm not talking about trivial algorithms such a k-means).

### Most "big data" isn't data mining

Now "Big data" is real. Google has Big data, and CERN also has big data. Most others probably don't. Data starts being big, when you need 1000 computers just to *store* it.

Big data technologies such as Hadoop are also real. They aren't always used sensibly (don't bother to run hadoop clusters less than 100 nodes - as this point you probably can get much better performance from well-chosen non-clustered machines), but of course people write such software.

But most of what is being done isn't data mining. It's [Extract, Transform, Load (ETL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load), so it is replacing data warehousing. Instead of using a database with structure, indexes and accelerated queries, the data is just dumped into hadoop, and when you have figured out what to do, you re-read all your data and extract the information you really need, tranform it, and load it into your excel spreadsheet. Because after selection, extraction and transformation, usually it's not "big" anymore.

### Data quality suffers with size

Many of the marketing promises of big data will not hold. Twitter produces much less insights for most companies than advertised (unless you are a teenie rockstar, that is); and the Twitter user base is *heavily biased*. Correcting for such a bias is hard, and needs highly experienced statisticians.

Bias from data is one problem - if you just collect some random data from the internet or an appliction, it will usually be not representative; in particular not of potential users. Instead, you will be overfittig to the existing heavy-users if you don't manage to cancel out these effects.

The other big problem is just noise. You have spam bots, but also other tools (think Twitter "trending topics" that cause reinforcement of "trends") that make the data much noiser than other sources. Cleaning this data is *hard*, and not a matter of technology but of statistical domain expertise. For example **Google Flu Trends** was repeatedly found to be rather inaccurate. It worked in some of the earlier years (maybe because of overfitting?) but is not anymore of good quality.

Unfortunately, a lot of big data users pay too little attention to this; which is probably one of the many reasons why most big data projects seem to fail (the others being incompetent management, inflated and unrealistic expectations, and lack of company culture and skilled people).

### Hadoop != data mining

Now for the second part of your question. Hadoop doesn't do data mining. Hadoop manages data storage (via HDFS, a very primitive kind of distributed database) and it schedules computation tasks, allowing you to run the computation on the same machines that store the data. It does *not* do any complex analysis.

There are some tools that try to bring data mining to Hadoop. In particular, **Apache Mahout can be called the official Apache attempt to do data mining on Hadoop**. Except that it is mostly a machine learning tool (machine learning != data mining; data mining sometimes uses methods from machine learning). Some parts of Mahout (such as clustering) are far from advanced. The problem is that **Hadoop is good for linear problems, but most data mining isn't linear**. And non-linear algorithms don't just scale up to large data; you need to carefully develop linear-time approximations and live with losses in accuracy - losses that must be smaller than what you would lose by simply working on smaller data.

A good example of this trade-off problem is k-means. K-means actually is a (mostly) linear problem; so it can be somewhat run on Hadoop. A single iteration is linear, and if you had a good implementation, it would scale well to big data. However, the number of iterations until convergence also grows with data set size, and thus it isn't really linear. However, as this is a statistical method to find "means", the results actually do not improve much with data set size. So while you can run k-means on big data, it does not make a whole lot of sense - you could just take a sample of your data, run a highly-efficient single-node version of k-means, and the results will be just as good. Because the extra data just gives you some extra digits of precision of a value that you do not need to be that precise.

Since this applies to quite a lot of problems, actual data mining on Hadoop doesn't seem to kick off. Everybody tries to do it, and a lot of companies sell this stuff. But it doesn't really work much better than the non-big version. But as long as customers want to buy this, companies will sell this functionality. And as long as it gets you a grant, researchers will write papers on this. Whether it works or not. That's life.

There are a few cases where these things work. Google search is an example, and Cern. But also image recognition (but not using Hadoop, clusters of GPUs seem to be the way to go there) has recently benefited from an increase in data size. But in any of these cases, you have rather clean data. Google indexes everything; Cern discards any non-interesting data, and only analyzes interesting measurements - there are no spammers feeding their spam into Cern... and in image analysis, you train on preselected relevant images, not on say webcams or random images from the internet (and if so, you treat them as random images, not as representative data).

Answer (score 4):

What is the difference between big data and Hadoop?

A: The difference between big data and the open source software program Hadoop is a distinct and fundamental one. The former is an asset, often a complex and ambiguous one, while the latter is a program that accomplishes a set of goals and objectives for dealing with that asset.

Big data is simply the large sets of data that businesses and other parties put together to serve specific goals and operations. Big data can include many different kinds of data in many different kinds of formats. For example, businesses might put a lot of work into collecting thousands of pieces of data on purchases in currency formats, on customer identifiers like name or Social Security number, or on product information in the form of model numbers, sales numbers or inventory numbers. All of this, or any other large mass of information, can be called big data. As a rule, it’s raw and unsorted until it is put through various kinds of tools and handlers.

Hadoop is one of the tools designed to handle big data. Hadoop and other software products work to interpret or parse the results of big data searches through specific proprietary algorithms and methods. Hadoop is an open-source program under the Apache license that is maintained by a global community of users. It includes various main components, including a MapReduce set of functions and a Hadoop distributed file system (HDFS).

The idea behind MapReduce is that Hadoop can first map a large data set, and then perform a reduction on that content for specific results. A reduce function can be thought of as a kind of filter for raw data. The HDFS system then acts to distribute data across a network or migrate it as necessary.

Database administrators, developers and others can use the various features of Hadoop to deal with big data in any number of ways. For example, Hadoop can be used to pursue data strategies like clustering and targeting with non-uniform data, or data that doesn't fit neatly into a traditional table or respond well to simple queries.

See the article posted at http://www.shareideaonline.com/cs/what-is-the-difference-between-big-data-and-hadoop/

Thanks
Ankush

Answer (score 4):

This answer is really intended to add some specificity to the excellent answer from Anony-Mousse.

There's a lot of debate over exactly what Big Data is.  Anony-Mousse called out a lot of the issues here around the overuse of terms like analytics, big data, and data mining, but there are a few things I want to provide more detail on.

**Big Data**

For practical purposes, the best definition I've heard of big data is data that is inconvenient or does not function in a traditional relational database. This could be data of 1PB that cannot be worked with or even just data that is 1GB but has 5,000 columns.

This is a loose and flexible definition. There are always going to be setups or data management tools which can work around it, but, this is where tools like Hadoop, MongoDB, and others can be used more efficiently that prior technology.

What can we do with data that is this inconvenient/large/difficult to work with? It's difficult to simply look at a spreadsheet and to find meaning here, so we often use data mining and machine learning.

**Data Mining**

This was called out lightly above - my goal here is to be more specific and hopefully to provide more context. Data mining generally applies to somewhat supervised analytic or statistical methods for analysis of data. These may fit into regression, classification, clustering, or collaborative filtering. There's a lot of overlap with machine learning, however, this is still generally driven by a user rather that unsupervised or automated execution, which defines machine learning fairly well.

**Machine Learning**

Often, machine learning and data mining are used interchangeably. Machine learning encompasses a lot of the same areas as data mining but also includes AI, computer vision, and other unsupervised tasks. The primary difference, and this is definitely a simplification, is that user input is not only unnecessary but generally unwanted. The goal is for these algorithms or systems to self-optimize and to improve, rather than an iterative cycle of development.

Answer (score 3):

Big Data is a TERM which consists of collection of frameworks and tools which could do miracles with the very large data sets including Data Mining.

`Hadoop` is a framework which will split the very large data sets into blocks(by default 64 mb) then it will store it in `HDFS` (Hadoop Distributed File System) and then when its execution logic(`MapReduce`) comes with any `bytecode` to process the data stored at `HDFS`. It will  take the split based on block(splits can be configured) and impose the extraction and computation via Mapper and Reducer process. By this way you could do ETL process, Data Mining, Data Computation, etc.,

I would like to conclude that Big Data is a terminology which could play with very large data sets. `Hadoop` is a framework which can do parallel processing very well with its components and services. By that way you can acquire Data mining too..

Answer (score 2):

Big Data is the term people use to say how storage is cheap and easy these days and how data is available to be analyzed.

Data Mining is the process of trying to extract useful information from data.

Usually, Data Mining is related to Big Data for 2 reasons

1. when you have lots of data, patterns are not so evident, so someone could not just inspect and say "hah". He/she needs tools for that.
2. for many times lots of data can improve the statistical meaningful to your analysis because your sample is bigger.

Can we say hadoop is dois data mining in parallel? What is hadoop? Their site says

```
The Apache Hadoop software library is a framework that allows for the 
distributed processing of large data sets across clusters of computers 
using simple programming models
```

So the "parallel" part of your statement is true. The "data mining" part of it is not necessarily. You can just use hadoop to summarize tons of data and this is not necessarily data mining, for example. But for most cases, you can bet people are trying to extract useful info from big data using hadoop, so this is kind of a yes.

Comment: In most cases, they seem to use Hadoop for ETL, then analyze the no-longer-big data with traditional software, including Excel (so not really "data mining" either).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that BigData is a modernized framework for addressing the new business needs.
As many people might know BigData is all about 3 v's Volume,Variety and Velocity. BigData is a need to leverage a variety of data (structured and un structured data) and using clustering technique to address volume issue and also getting results in less time ie.velocity.

Where as Datamining is on ETL principle .i.e finding useful information from large datasets using modelling techinques. There are many BI tools available in market to achieve this.